# Destructuring Assignment to Pass an object as function's parameter

Tags: javascript, object-destructuring

I am learning Javascript on freeCodeCamp, and I came across passing an Object as a function Parameter through restructuring Assignment

I was asked to

**"Use destructuring assignment within the argument to the function half to send only max and min inside the function."**

```
const stats = {
  max: 56.78,
  standard_deviation: 4.34,
  median: 34.54,
  mode: 23.87,
  min: -0.75,
  average: 35.85
};

// Only change code below this line
const half = ({ max, min }) => (max + min) / 2.0; 
// Only change code above this line
```

**//The solution doesn't make sense to me since it doesn't even mention stats. How come does it work? Can someone explain it please. thank you in advance.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course the function doesn't mention `stats` explicitly - the function cannot know the name of a variable that might be passed to it

```js
const stats = {
  max: 56.78,
  standard_deviation: 4.34,
  median: 34.54,
  mode: 23.87,
  min: -0.75,
  average: 35.85
};

const half = ({ max, min }) => (max + min) / 2.0;

console.log(half(stats));
```

The signature of your function `({ max, min })` reads like this:

From any (first) argument passed to this function, assume it's an object that has `max` and `min` properties. Make those available under their name as local variables inside the function body.